# Conditionally set a field of a Protobuf message

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, protobuf-java

I am creating a converter method between two protobuf messages A and B:

```
message A {
 optional int64 id = 1;
 optional string name = 2;
}
 
message B {
 optional int64 id = 1;
 optional C c= 2;
}

message C {
 optional string name = 1; 
}
```

My code is the following:

```
    private A convertFromBToA(B b) {
        return A.newBuilder()
                .setId(B.getId())
                .setName(b.hasC() ? b.getC().getName() : null).build();
    }
```

Essentially, I only want to set the name field of message A if B's C field has a name field. Otherwise I want to leave A's name field unset. Is this the correct way to do so?

Answer (score 2):

Just use an `if` to conditionally call `setName` only if you have a name to set, rather than always calling `setName` even when there is no argument to give it:

```
A a = A.newBuilder().setId(B.getId())

if (b.hasC()) {
  a = a.setName(b.getC());
}

return a.build();
```